# How to make vgg pytorch's ptl size smaller on android?

Tags: android, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

```
import torch
# import joblib
from torch.utils.mobile_optimizer import optimize_for_mobile
from torchvision.models.vgg import vgg16
import torch, torchvision.models

# lb = joblib.load('lb.pkl')
device = torch.device('cuda:0')
#device = torch.device('cpu')#'cuda:0')
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
model = vgg16().to(device)



# model = torchvision.models.vgg16()
path = 'model-22222.pth'
torch.save(model.state_dict(), path) # nothing else here
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path))

#model.load_state_dict(torch.load('./model-76-0.7754.pth'))

scripted_module = torch.jit.script(model)
optimized_scripted_module = optimize_for_mobile(scripted_module)
optimized_scripted_module._save_for_lite_interpreter("model-76-0.7754.ptl")
```

The `optimize_for_mobile` seems does not make the ptl file smaller, it's about 527M, too large on Android. How to make it smaller?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using quantization:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html

Usually it allows to reduce the size of the model 2x-4x times with little or no loss of accuracy.

Example:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.mobile_optimizer import optimize_for_mobile
from torchvision.models.vgg import vgg16

device = torch.device("cpu")
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
model = vgg16().to(device)

backend = "qnnpack"
model.qconfig = torch.quantization.get_default_qconfig(backend)
torch.backends.quantized.engine = backend
model_static_quantized = torch.quantization.prepare(model, inplace=False)
model_static_quantized = torch.quantization.convert(
    model_static_quantized, inplace=False
)

scripted_module = torch.jit.script(model_static_quantized)
optimized_scripted_module = optimize_for_mobile(scripted_module)
optimized_scripted_module._save_for_lite_interpreter("model_quantized.ptl")
```

Apart from it I would try to use the architectures more suitable for mobile phones because VGG is kinda old and has not a great size/accuracy ratio. You can distillate your trained VGG model into smaller one with [Knowledge distillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_distillation).

Comment: But the code runs error:`RuntimeError: quantized engine QNNPACK is not supported`, it seems not support QNNPACK. Which quantized engine can I use? Thanks

Comment: If you are planning to run your model on ARM phones then you may need qnnpack. Please refer to the documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html. What version of pytorch are you using? Maybe you need to update pytorch.

Comment: Thanks. But the size only smaller 50%, how to reduce to about 5%. The size is too big yet. Not fit for the mobile phone users.@u1234x1234

Comment: Is there any other solutions, for example use onnx , ncnn or transform into tensorflow lite? @u1234x1234

Comment: Sure you can export your model from pytorch and use ncnn or tensorflow-lite but those are inference frameworks - given a trained model they allow you to make predictions efficiently. You can use int8 inference so the model size will be 4x lower than the original float32 model. But if you need to reduce the size of the model even more than you might need other tools.